# Tomcat configuration for single IP address with multiple domains and SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I am trying to configure Tomcat to serve the same content to two different domains with different SSL certificates but the same IP address.  I have created two connectors however even though the domain is different I am getting the following error on startup:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Is it even possible to allow tomcat to serve two domains, with different SSL certificates on the same IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#General_Tips_on_Running_SSL) Tomcat 8.5 supports SNI

Alternatively, you could add subject alternative name extensions for the additional host names you want to cover.

Comment: I was using Tomcat 7 and after a bunch of research found the option for SNI configuration.  After upgrading to Tomcat 8.5 and adding multiple SSLHostConfig's for different hostnames it works perfectly.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help